# No suitable image found when setting up nendo

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I keep running into this error:

```
/Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ML_Models/music_gen.py", line 22, in <module>
    nd = Nendo(config=NendoConfig(plugins=["nendo_plugin_musicgen"]))
  File "/Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nendo/main.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._load_plugins(plugin_names=plugin_names)
  File "/Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nendo/main.py", line 141, in _load_plugins
    plugin_instance = self._load_plugin(module_name=module_name)
  File "/Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nendo/main.py", line 129, in _load_plugin
    raise schema.NendoPluginLoadingError(
nendo.schema.exception.NendoPluginLoadingError: Failed to import plugin 'nendo_plugin_musicgen'. Error: dlopen(/Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/av/_core.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/av/.dylibs/libavformat.60.3.100.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/av/.dylibs/libX11.6.dylib: cannot load 'libX11.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
        /Users/adelabdalla/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/av/.dylibs/libX11.6.dylib: cannot load 'libX11.6.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff including upgrading Python, upgrading brew, downloading ffmpeg etc. but cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

[PyPi states:](https://pypi.org/project/nendo/)

> It is recommended to use a virtual environment for installing nendo core, in order to avoid dependency conflicts. Furthermore, the following software packages need to be installed in your system:

- Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libsndfile1 libportaudio2
- Mac OS: brew install ffmpeg libsndfile portaudio
- Windows: Windows support is currently under development. For the time being, we highly recommend using Windows Subsystem for Linux and then following the linux instructions. **If you still want to try to get Nendo Core to work natively on Windows, you will need to install the following software packages: ffmpeg, libsndfile, and portaudio**.